# Struts - Loading result-templates (like JSP) from JAR-Files

Tags: java, jsp, templates, jar, struts

How can I define it in the struts framework, when I would like to load templates (JSP, ZUL etc.) from different JAR-Files?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand there should be no additional configuration as soon as all your JARs are accessible from struts jar (usually if they are in WEB-IN/lib) and property set up in web.xml (may be required for non-JSP templates).